# How can one determine the current region within an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

`Regions.getCurrentRegion()` returns null from within an AWS Lambda function.  It seems that `Regions.getCurrentRegion()` is not supported from within an AWS Lambda function.  Is there an alternative way to determine which region the lambda function is running in?

NOTE:  AWS Lambda function is written in Java.

Answer (score 78):

You can read the `AWS_REGION` environment variable and use the `Regions.fromName` function to parse that into a useable region.

```
Regions.fromName(System.getenv("AWS_REGION"))
```

The advantage of this over the ARN parsing approach is that you do not need a Context object which means you can use it outside of your handler function.

Source: [AWS's Lambda environment variables docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime).

Comment: This is documented in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks @pba - I've updated my answer to reflect that as a better source.

Answer (score 22):

All Lambda containers has environment variables set `$AWS_REGION`

From Java Code in Lambda.You can access it as below

```
System.getenv("AWS_REGION")
```

Comment: for Lambda on nodejs, it is  "process.env.AWS_REGION"

Answer (score 20):

For anyone looking to do this in Python:

```
import os
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
    print(my_region)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'Hello from {my_region}!')
    }
```

Comment: the import and syntax works but the code doesn't print region in the lambda function logs.

Comment: @ShikharChaudhary what region are you in?

Comment: I am in eu-west-1.

Answer (score 13):

The `context` object that is passed to your Lambda function has an attribute called `invokedFunctionArn`.  The ARN is of the format:

```
arn:aws:<service>:<region>:<account_id>:<resource>
```

So you could split this string on the `:` character and find the region associated with the Lambda function.

Note: In java you would call the `getInvokedFunctionArn()` getter of the context object.

Comment: The `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable is also available. This is available outside the handler and there is no need to parse it. See my answer for code.

Comment: Note that this environment variable is not present in all runtime environments.  As you show, it does work for Java.

Comment: Can you give some more details on the circumstances in which this is not set @garnaat? This shouldn't be specific to the JVM.

Comment: You're right.  I just ran tests in Python and NodeJS and it is present in both.  I'm not sure when this was added but I don't think it was there in earlier versions of Lambda.  This is an easier and more reliable way of finding the region than parsing the ARN.

Comment: But if someone wants to find account id then lambda does not provide any environment variable, this will be the only approach to use

Answer (score 8):

If anyone looking to get the region in Node JS. This will be work

```
process.env.AWS_REGION
```

Answer (score 5):

1) You can use environment variable and access it as

```
System.getenv("AWS_REGION")
```

> Following is a list of environment variables that are part of the AWS
>   Lambda execution environment and made available to Lambda functions.
>   The table below indicates which ones are reserved by AWS Lambda and
>   can't be changed, as well as which ones you can set when creating your
>   Lambda function. For more information on using environment variables
>   with your Lambda function

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-environment-variables.html

2) You can read the AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable

```
Regions.fromName(System.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As its javadoc states `Regions.getCurrentRegion()` is relevant in the AWS EC2 context only. In other contexts it returns `null` as it does in the AWS Lambda context.

AWS Lambda by default defines the `AWS_REGION` environmental variable holding the region name. The value can be read by `System.getenv("AWS_REGION")`.

Answer (score 1):

Although using the `AWS_REGION` environment variable will work in most cases, I've found that with a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/), this variable will resolve to the region from which the content was served (i.e. the closest region to the client). Using the `invokedFunctionArn` value from the `context` object will not work either for the same reason. Here is the `context` I received when invoking a Lambda in `us-east-1` from a location closest to `us-east-2`:

```json
{
  "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
  "functionVersion": "6",
  "functionName": "us-east-1.<FUNCTION_NAME>",
  "memoryLimitInMB": "128",
  "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/us-east-1.<FUNCTION NAME>",
  "logStreamName": "2020/09/04/[6]<LOG STREAM NAME",
  "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:<ACCOUNT ID>:function:us-east-1.<FUNCTION NAME>:6",
  "awsRequestId": "0fa5f5c3-90ea-41d5-b3c3-1714ccdf1b17"
}
```

So, the solution that I've found works consistently between Lambda@Edge and other Lambdas is to retrieve the region from the `functionName` value from the `context` object. Here's how I am doing this with Node.js:

```js
functionName.split('.')[0];
```

Comment: Do we need to use this `getFunction-Property` : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#getFunction-property

Comment: @RahulAhire - no, it's available on the [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) passed into the lambda. The event signature for a lambda handler is `async function(event, context)` if running async, or `function(event, context, callback)` if running the callback way. [See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) for more details on what's available when the lambda is invoked.