# How to get the AWS Region in a Javascript/Nodejs Lambda Function:

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How do I identify the region from within a Nodejs/Javascript AWS Lambda function?

The `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable gives a ReferenceError (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428783/how-can-one-determine-the-current-region-within-an-aws-lambda-function/37264097#37264097), which is for Java, not Node/Javascript.)

I realize I can get the "invokedFunctionArn" from the context object and parse it for the region, but it seems like there should be a more direct way.

Comment: Afaik the only way is to parse the arn

Comment: While it is not impossible to hack the way out to get the info; in my opinion, it is would be easier to feed in the REGION details as part of configuration details or environment info [i.e. explicitly add it to the code / config]

Answer (score 49):

Use the environment variable:

```
process.env.AWS_REGION
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables

Comment: The link changed; it's now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the context that is passed in. There maybe more goodies to discover there.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Function name:', context.functionName);
    context.succeed();
};
```

I don't know anything that simply tells you the region. An ugly hack would be exec-ing something in the containing OS (linux) and hoping for the info to show up. `uname -a` perhaps.

I'm just curious. What do you need it for? Some kind of debugging info?

Comment: The lambda will be deployed in different regions and consequently will have region-specific configuration values (SNS topics, for one).

Comment: Additionally (and most importantly), the config file (json) contains the config for all regions, with the key as the region.

Answer (score 0):

There just doesn't seem to be a more direct way to identify the region in a running lambda function, other than using context.invokedFunctionArn property.

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
exports.handler = (event,context, callback) => {
    var arnList = (context.invokedFunctionArn).split(":");
    var lambdaRegion = arnList[3] //region is the fourth element in a lambda function arn


    //more code
}
```